# Calling a method from another class that removes views

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am hoping this is an easy answer and it is just because I am new to this.

I am trying from inside another class be able to remove views that exist in another class.

In the class I am calling the method I do this.

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[viewController closeNotifiactions];
```

And then in my other class here is the method where I am trying to remove the views.  If I place an NSLog in this method it is called and works, however the removeFromSuperview codes do not work.

```
-(void)closeNotifiactions
{
    [spinner removeFromSuperview];
    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And in my .h file I reference the closeNotifications method like this: `-(void)closeNotifiactions;`

Is there something I need to do different to make the closeNotifications part work?  Thank you!

Comment: Where do you initialize viewController?  ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

Comment: Make sure that you are not creating a new controller object instead of removing from existing controller object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSNotification to access another class properly.

Class A:

//Create NSNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closeNotifiactions) name:@"notification" object:nil];
```

Class B:
//Just Call NSNotification to call that method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notification" object:nil];
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewController *move = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];;
        [move closeNotifiactions];
        [move release];
```